# Logic to display the correct selected thumbnails?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress - I am wondering if it could work with posts'feature images and links as content?

In form, there would have brochure images (PDF thumbnails) with checkboxes. The user will select one or more thumbnails. On thank you, there would be correct selected thumbnails for the user to download pdf files.

So how to have posts display with checkboxes and then on thank you, how to display correct ones with links wrapped around them?

the help or insight would be appreciated. The image can help u to see what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

OR we do static things - how do I get the checkbox selected then display the correct pdf?

Comment: The images are featured images of posts? How are those posts linked to the PDF?

Comment: @janw, images would be uploaded using feature image via post. yeah that's the problem - how to link feature image to pdf :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea, not very dynamic:

1. upload the pdf
2. copy the url of the pdf
3. make a new post (maybe create a custom post type for this)
4. paste the pdf url in a '[custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)'
5. add the featured image to the post
6. publish the post

on the frontend

1. [query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) all posts which have a pdf on them.(based on posttype/tags/category whatever)
2. Make a list
3. show the featured image (you know how)
4. save selection on post ID (on submit)
5. show selection on post ID , get both the featured image and the pdf link.

Not the most graceful solution but that's how I would do it.
I would use a custom post type. Since the post doesn't need an title or body(text)

Comment: seems to be a good way about this with custom post type got to look it up .. thanks for the help

Comment: Custom post types: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types A pretty and user friendly way to display custom fields: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box